# On Scrolled comes to top automatically

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener, endlessscroll

I am implementing endless recycler view. Data is getting fine from server aslo scroll down getting down and show it. But on scroll it automatically comes to top again and again. I implemented number of solutions but doesn't work. Here is bit of code.

```
private int postNo = 15;

public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    if (!lastTime) {
        if (dy > 0) { // check for scroll down
            visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisibleItems = ((GridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                postNo = postNo + 15;
                getDataFromUrl(postNo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is when I scroll down app increase num of items and it should scroll fine.

```
  www.............." + postNo";
```

Comment: post your code and xml file

Comment: give me your mail

Comment: you can post your code here use `edit` question .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769951/on-scrolled-to-add-items-in-recyclerview-always-comes-to-top-automatically-when

Comment: check link plz.